# how to add user on gcp cloud sql replica from aws rds mysql master

Tags: mysql, replication, google-cloud-sql

I faced a problem during configure gcp cloud sql replica from aws rds mysql.

i followed this post step by step. 
https://medium.com/@eddi.alim/mysql-aws-rds-replication-to-google-cloud-sql-f3022e9ff4

in this post, he successfully add user his google cloud sql replica. 
and he successfully accessed replication database using new user.

but i couldn't.

when i tried to create user on my gcp cloud replica then i faced a message like this " read only replica can't support creating user"

i don't know what's wrong...

i asked him on his blog. but he doesn't anwser yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/129571002) and is currently being resolved by the Cloud SQL engineering team.

There is no ETA for a resolution at this time.